# How to get data from datalist

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, datalist

I have problem with my datalist
i want to create view use jquery from here http://jsfiddle.net/aino/9yyVd/

i already create datalist to get data froom sql

aspx:

```
<asp:DataList ID="DStuffingInfo" RepeatDirection="Vertical" RepeatLayout="Table" RepeatColumns="1" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
<table>
<tr><td><asp:Label ID="NameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("EXF")).ToString("dd/MM/yy") %>'/>
<td></tr>
</table>
```

C#

```
public void DStuff(){
con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT ShipMode, COUNTRY, EXF, ClassItem FROM mexp3 WHERE ShipMode like '%1 X 20FT%' " +
        "GROUP BY ShipMode, COUNTRY, EXF, ClassItem order by EXF", con);
DataTable dt = new DataTable(); 
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(dt);
    DStuffingInfo.DataSource = dt;
    DStuffingInfo.DataBind();
    con.Close();
}
```

this is what i get

> 07/04/14
>   11/04/14
>   10/04/14

what actually i want my data shown is just one data but when i click button or anything it would be change to next data...I use JQUERY

example:

> 07/04/14 <-- when click will change to 11/04/14

Comment: In your example, the values are loaded from `li`. You can use the same right?

Comment: when i use li ...i get the same result
all data shown at the same time

Comment: means all data is visible? is the visual effect working with all data visible?

Comment: i just found that if all data visible the jquery effect is not working